# "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'net'" when trying to use Ansible localhost to connect to a Windows Shared Folder

Tags: linux, ansible, network-share, localhost

I am unable to use Ansible `localhost` (Linux) to connect to a shared folder on a Windows Server.

I am getting `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'net'`. However, I have checked that my file path to the shared folder is correct, so I am not sure how to resolve this error.

The shared folder task as written in my playbook:

```yaml
- name: Connect to shared folder
  command: net use * '\\10.15.250.110\mixeddocs' /user:{{ username }} {{ password }} /p:no
  become: yes
```

The full error message:

```json
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload_tjjro3uh/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2022, in run_command
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "net use '*' '\\\\10.15.250.110\\mixeddocs' /user:newuser Password /p:no",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "net use * '\\\\10.15.250.110\\mixeddocs' /user:newuser Password /p:no",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'net'",
    "rc": 2,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages says that the *binary* `net` is not found on the system. Hence, `b'net'`.
This is an expected output because the `net` command is not available on Linux, it is a Windows command.

How to mount a Windows share in Linux manually you can find in this article:
[How to mount Windows share on Red Hat Enterprise Linux system using CIFS?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/448263)

Since you want to do it in Ansible on the localhost by judging your output, you can do something like this:

#### mount_samba_localhost.yml:

```yaml
- name: Setup SMB share
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars:
    username: smb_username
    password: smb_password
    domain: domain
    share_path: '//10.15.250.110/mixeddocs'
    mount_point: /mnt/my_mount_point
    credentials_file: /root/smb_credentials

  tasks:
    - name: Install cifs-utils
      ansible.builtin.package:
        name: cifs-utils
        state: present

    - name: Create directory for mount point
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: "{{ mount_point }}"
        state: directory

    - name: Create credentials file
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        dest: "{{ credentials_file }}"
        content: |
          username={{ username }}
          password={{ password }}
          domain={{ domain }}
        mode: 0600
        owner: root
        group: root

    - name: Mount Windows share folder
      ansible.posix.mount:
        path: "{{ mount_point }}"
        src: "{{ share_path }}"
        fstype: cifs
        opts: 'credentials={{ credentials_file }}'
        state: mounted
```

This creates a credentials file in the root directory. In general, it is a best practice to avoid adding plain text passwords in the `fstab` file for security reasons. That's why a separate credentials file is created. Furthermore, an entry will be added to the `fstab` to ensure the mount persists across system reboots by `ansible.posix.mount`.

Though, I recommend using `NFS-shares` instead of `CIFS`.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I will try this. May I know why NFS instead of CIFS?

Comment: Also, if I want to use NFS, do I just replace all the CIFS with NFS? Are the modules required still the same?

Comment: The advice is actually when the majority of your environment are UNIX/Linux systems. However, if the majority of your systems are Windows please keep using CIFS. Very nice info where both are getting compared:  [CIFS vs NFS](https://www.educba.com/cifs-vs-nfs/)

Comment: So I tried your solution, replaced CIFS with NFS and created the credentials file in a non-root directory. Unfortunately, it failed at the mount task. The error is: "msg": "Error mounting /mnt/my_mount_point: mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format\n"

Comment: NFS is a different thing than CIFS. If you want to mount NFS, you should create the NFS-Export on the server which is going to export the mount, in this case on `10.15.250.110`.  
And then you can mount the NFS on the specific Linux Machine. [Deploy NFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/nfs/deploy-nfs)If your server only has the CIFS share configured, stick with `fstype: cifs`.  Read this to get additional information on how to mount different types with Ansible: [Ansible mount_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html)